# Why do these divs begin to wrap if bootstrap is fluid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Everything's all nice and fluid here:

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3288/

```
<div class = 'color-strip row-fluid'>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>  <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
</div>
```

It's all percentage based, so no matter how wide you go, those stripes take up the same amount of proportional space. So why is it that, **when I make the screen mobile sized, the divs begin to wrap?** Really irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's due to padding.
if you override `col-xs-1` like this :

```
.col-xs-1 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

it working.

or if you dont want override bootstrap, set in style :

```
<div class = 'color-strip  row'>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: yellow; height: 20px'></div>
    <div class = 'col-xs-1' style= 'padding: 0;background-color: red; height: 20px'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: or create an override stylesheet and ensure it's read after bootstrap.css. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `row-fluid` in bootstrap 3, just `row`. And rows need to be in a `container`.